# Unable to take snapshot of launched app programatically. Getting mDrawingCache as NULL

Tags: android

I am being able to take snapshot of Hello World app through below code.'

```
private void takeScreenshot() 
``{
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have launched another app (excel) using Intent (getLaunchIntent for package method). Now I want to take screenshot of launched app. I tried to call the same method as above and changed the View as below:

View v1 = findViewByID(android.R.id.content);

But when I try to retrieve Drawing Cache through 
Bitmap cac = v1.getDrawingCache()

I am getting cac as NULL. How can I retrieve the view of launched app so that getDrawingCache does not return NULL?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I retrieve the view of launched app

You can't, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

You are welcome to use the media projection APIs to take screenshots on Android 5.0+, with user permission.

Comment: @McflyDroid: Only from your development machine.

Comment: Thanks I could do it using uiautomator